# How to find baseAddress in Wix?

Tags: xml, wcf, wix, installation, base-address

I have a Wcfservice that uses Wix for setup.

During installation I have a Gui that collects different settings and then changes these settings in Product.wxs. But I'm having difficulty finding the baseAddress setting I want to change.

My config file has this section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Default">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="OurServiceLibrary.OurService">
            <clear/>
                        <endpoint name="OurBasicHttpBinding" address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="OurServiceLibrary.IOurService" listenUriMode="Explicit"/>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <!-- The base-address must be updated with the correct url for the hosting machine. -->
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8081/ourservice"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And the code I'm using when I try to change the setting is:

```
<!--Put path to settings in local variable-->
<?define ServiceModelSettingsPath="//configuration/system.ServiceModel/services/service/host/baseAddresses/" ?>

<!--Modify settings with values entered in the installation UI-->
<util:XmlFile Id="ModifyServiceBaseAdress"
         Action="setValue"
         Permanent="yes"
         ElementPath="$(var.ServiceModelSettingsPath)/add"
         Name ="baseAddress"
         File="[#OurServiceSettingsFile]"
         Value="connectionString=[SERVICEBASEADRESS_VALUE]"
         SelectionLanguage="XPath"
         Sequence="1" />
```

When trying to run the setup I get an error saying that "Failed to find node: //configuration/system.ServiceModel/services/service/host/baseAddresses//add in XML file"

Obviously the path to the node is wrong but I can't see how, can anyone help me?

Comment: ServiceModel - serviceModel Case sensitivity issue?  I don't think the double slash after //add will affect it.

Answer (score 0):

That was it, a simple spelling error. The double slash doesn't do any difference. But changing to serviceModel in the path did.

Then I found another error, I dodn't need connectionString= when setting the value, only:

Value="[EVENTREPORTINGADDRESS_VALUE]"

Thanks!